# Android Studio Log.d doesn't work in Fragment of Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments, android-logcat

I have this code, a Fragment in Navigation drawer which makes a map with google maps API and also makes marks, and the log.d doesn't show in the Logcat box of the Android Studio, if somebody can help me so that I can do tests, thanks!!!
(I wrote this code because I want to create markers of Google Maps from FireBaseDatabase).

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;   
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference perdidosUbiRef = rootRef.child("Perdidos").child("Ubicación");


    public MapFragment() {            
    }

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;       
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //PON TITULO BAR
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mapa");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perdidosmap, container, false);

        mMapView= (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        mMapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;


                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //Request location updates:
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

                markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();   
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);


                //PROVA BASE DADES
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Float Lat = ds.child("Lat").getValue(Float.class);
                            Float Long = ds.child("Long").getValue(Float.class);

                            Log.d("ValuesofLat", "HELLOOO");

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                perdidosUbiRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);



                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng Barcelona = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(41.3818)), Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(2.1685)));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Barcelona).
                        title("Tetsuo").snippet("Es perro macarra"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Barcelona).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition
                        (cameraPosition ));



            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]
                                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {



                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Log.d is in this part of code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Float Lat = ds.child("Lat").getValue(Float.class);
                            Float Long = ds.child("Long").getValue(Float.class);

                            Log.d("ValuesofLat", "HELLOOO");

                        }
                    }
```

My Logcat's box
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLyWw.png)

Comment: Clear search bar from logcat's then it will show.

Comment: Its very simple thing that only you have to do is firstly select **show only selected project** option from your last right side Logcat's drop down

Comment: Value event listeners are asynchronous... You'll see the log when Firebase connects and fetches the data and starts the onDataChange callback. Till then the rest of the code will execute as this is non blocking

Comment: @Kushan but i put the Log.id outside the value event and it does the same

Comment: You aren't by any chance running realise build right? Because they won't show in release

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: i tryed this and neither:  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //PON TITULO BAR
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mapa");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perdidosmap, container, false);
        Log.d("ValuesofLat", "HELLOOO");

Comment: it only happens in this activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove **`ValuesofLat`**  from Search bar in your logcat and it will work fine

Just clear search bar from logcat's it will work fine

Check below image

[image]

clear search bar like below image and it will work  fine

[image]

Comment: this is not an answer you can tell this thing into comments.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer I just mentioned in comment normally

Comment: not is this, i want it shows the message HELLOOO from the log.id with ValuesofLat's tag, if i only clear search, it only shows all messages, i want it shows the previous message